# Circular Reference Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, circular-reference

we're replicating a complex spreadsheet in power BI as it can process the data far more quickly than excel.

I'm very new to Power BI so I am hoping this is a silly problem I've caused myself and can be worked around.

We have several calculated columns replicating the sums from excel. However, I'm getting the following error message when entering what *seems* to be one of the simpler sums.

[image: Error message]

there is no **obvious** circular reference that I can work out. We have a rank column to rank a cost value for a specific group (SAU - as seen in the screenshot) both the cost values and rank seem to be working fine and as we'd expect. The cost is calculated from several other calculated columns (none of which are referencing our problem column) but is just basic addition/multiplication.

What we're trying to achieve is a calculated column where it sums another number value called THP (found in another standard column) in the column called sum_THP_Rank for all records up until the current records rank. i.e. if we had 3 records for each SAU it would do the following:

[image: table]

the calculation which we were using that previously worked but now does not is as follows:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( DP_to_Prem[THP] ),
    FILTER ( DP_to_Prem, DP_to_Prem[Rank] <= EARLIER ( DP_to_Prem[Rank] ) ),
    FILTER ( DP_to_Prem, DP_to_Prem[SAU] = EARLIER ( DP_to_Prem[SAU] ) )
)
```

as I understand it, "calculate" can be susceptible to this error, as I'm new to DAX and PowerBI I'm struggling to find out how I'd work around this.

As requested, `Rank`:

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    FILTER ( DP_to_Prem, DP_to_Prem[SAU] = EARLIER ( DP_to_Prem[SAU] ) ),
    DP_to_Prem[LifeCost],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

Comment: I think the culprit is the `Rank` column. Can you add the code for that calculated column to your post?

Comment: I've added the code now :)

Comment: Yep. That's it. Your FILTER functions are referencing the entire table so you have a dependency of `Sum_THP_Rank` depends on `Rank` depends on `Sum_THP_Rank` since those columns are part of `DP_to_Prem`.

Comment: Hi Alexis, how would we go about removing that dependency is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try redefining `Rank` like this:

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    CALCULATETABLE ( DP_to_Prem, ALLEXCEPT ( DP_to_Prem, DP_to_Prem[SAU] ) ),
    DP_to_Prem[LifeCost],
    ,
    ASC
)
```